# Read a layered pdf, update the text layers with custom text and save it as pdf preserving the spot colors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

I have searched a lot but did not find an answer so hope this is not a duplicate question.

I have a pdf document, made in Adobe Illustrator with some text layers and spot colors for printing.

I need to read the pdf document in .net, get a specific text layer by name (As I know all the layers name in the pdf document.) change its text contents and save the pdf with a different file name.

I have even searched for different pdf libraries but couldn't find one fulfilling my needs.

What options do I have ? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: *change its text contents* - changing the text contents of a PDF programmatically (i.e. not interactively) generally is very fickle and prone to surprising artifacts. Probably the fact that you know the PDFs all have been produced by AI can help you, though.

Comment: @mkl: Hmm, I tried another thing, Instead of accessing the text layer by name, I used Aspose pdf library, wrote the same text on all layers like {placeholder-1} and then replace the text "placeholder-1" to the text from the system and save the pdf. The problem is the text in my pdf is in an arch form but after replacing the text and saving , the arch became a straight line text:(

Comment: That's one of the reasons why text replacement is bad... PDF itself does not know how to put text into such an arch. Thus, each letter is simply individually positioned. This, in turn, dies not allow easy text replacement, especially with text with a different number of glyphs or different widths.

Comment: I checked and can have ".svg" format for the ultimate output instead of ".pdf". I tried to export the document from illustrator into ".svg" and ".fxg", opened the .fxg in notepad and it had all the tags with designs. I did a quick find and replace for the specific text and saved it and opened it in illustrator and it kept all the designs and stuff with the changed text. But for the ".svg" when opened in notepad I can't find the text I am looking for(some kind of encoded). Can I save svg from illustrator so I can change replace the text as then I might be able to replace the text in code :)?